# Marquee with Css3 Animation

Tags: html, css

i have some problems with my marquee , i need to make it pure css and css3 . so i almost do it , but some errors show up . 
take alook

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJvqLL

my CSS :

```
.cssmarquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
}

.cssmarquee div {

  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: cssmarquee 5s linear infinite;
    background-color:blue;
    color: #FFF;
}
.cssmarquee div:hover {
animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes cssmarquee {
  0% { left: 100%; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

- The problem is the `.cssmarquee div` not a fixed width . so i can`t pass his fixed width  to the @keyframe  100% { left: ???? } , so you need to wait after the 100% width to finish and repeat it again  .  Can any one help me

Comment: Why are not using the marquee tag ?

Comment: @GabrielSINM , its not support from chrome :(

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of `left` your could use `transform`. Like this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waBNzj)

```
@keyframes cssmarquee {
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Look at this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doPaNO) for left to right.
I updated this style:

```
.cssmarquee div {   
  width: 100%;
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
```

I gave it a width of 100% and set the default transform to 100%

**UPDATE** 2:

Look at this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOEbeJ). It returns to using `left` instead of `transform` and also uses `width:auto`

Comment: its not come from right to left !! are you sure is that the answer !

Comment: is thir any way to make the blue div is auto witdh :(

Comment: You can set the width to auto if you want, but auto will only make the width as wide as the content that is contained in the div

Comment: The problem is the content maybe  be more of 100% :( maybe will be full article or somthing not one line :(